# Differential equation note

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} -\frac{dy}{dx} = 0.$$  The only function satisfy this equation is  $y=e^x $.  How I can use differential equation to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean? you just did it for $y=e^x$ didn't you?

Comment: @Paul yes.  But how I can apply differential equation  rules to find this function?

Comment: You could show it with the Laplace transform, with the characteristic polynomial or with substitution and integration by parts, and probably a few more ways.

Comment: You will need two initial conditions to specify y uniquely e.g. the values of y and its derivative when x = 0 or the value of y at 2 values of x.

Comment: The original phrasing of the question was confusing and confused. The current phrasing is flat out wrong. y=e^x is certainly not the only function satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 5):

$$y''-y'=0$$
$$\frac{y''}{y'}=1$$
$$\log|y'|=x+C_1$$
$$y'=e^{x+C_1}=ke^x$$
$$y=ke^x+C_2$$

Comment: It assumes here that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $y'$ will not be equal to zero? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Call $z=y'$ so $z$ is a solution of the equation $z'=z$ whose general solution is $z(x)=k\cdot e^x$ and therefore the general solution to $y''-y'=0$ is $y(x)=k\cdot e^x+h$ where $k$ and $h$ are constants

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} -\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
Multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$: $$e^{-x}\frac d{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac d{dx}[e^{-x}.\frac{dy}{dx}]=0$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$: $$e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx}=a$$
Again repeating the feat after taking $e^{-x}$ to the RHS: $$y=\int ae^xdx$$
And thus, the answer is $$\boxed{ae^{x}+b}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = e^{mx}$
$$ y'(x)= me^{mx}  , \ \  y''(x)= m^2e^{mx}$$

Substitute the above into your differential equation:
$$m^2 -m = 0 \implies m = 0 \ \text{or} \ 1 $$

Solution:

$$ y = A+ B e^x$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: What tempts you to substitute $e^{mx}$ for $y$?

Comment: @Aditya: This is part of a standard technique for homogeneous ODEs with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

$e^x$ is defined as the solution to that differential equation. Therefore it is true by definition.

Comment: The OP's edit made this terse remark seem unhelpful.  Perhaps including the defining differential equation in the Answer would avoid this.